# onclick delegate is triggered only once

Tags: c#, delegates, outlook-addin

I am writing an outlook add-in that adds a menu to outlook. **Although I set delegate to an action for the menu it seems like it is being removed after one call to the delegate - one click on the menu item**. next time user clicks it is not getting to my delegate.
code example:

```
menuCommand = (Office.CommandBarButton)cmdBarControl.Controls.Add(
Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, missing, missing, missing, true);

menuCommand.Caption = "&Generate weekly...";
menuCommand.Tag = "Generate";
menuCommand.FaceId = 65;

menuCommand.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Core._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(
menuCommand_Generate_Click);

menuCommand = (Office.CommandBarButton)cmdBarControl.Controls.Add(
    Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, missing, missing, missing, true);

menuCommand.Caption = "&About";
menuCommand.Tag = "About";
menuCommand.FaceId = 65;

menuCommand.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Core._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(
menuCommand_About_Click);
menuCommand.BeginGroup = true;
```

What should I do in order for the menu to trigger the action every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is menuitem a local variable? , 
becouse then the garbage collector might clean in up once it falls out of scope.

Try keeping the variable in a global object.

Comment: I now see you are re-using the same variable for a 2nd button. This will also cause the first button to be candidate for garbage collection.